# System and hardware information Library or open source project

Tags: .net, dll, system-information

I need a  System and hardware information library written with .net/C#. 
I am developing an application like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Do you know opensource projectlike this ?

network bandwith, Cpu/Ram usage, Hdd free space, process control, ..

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the information you need, you can get from the `ManagementObjectSearcher`-class.

Like this

```
ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk"); 

s.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(obj => new {
    obj.Path,
    Properties = obj.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>().Select (pd => new { pd.Name, pd.Value }),
    IsOk = (obj.Properties["Status"] != null ? obj.Properties["Status"].Value : "")
});
```

That would give you an `IEnumerable<>` of the anonymous type, which contains the properties of all disks your computer has.

Check this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx